# Spring Framework: ContextRefreshedEvent is fired multiple times

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Under certain cases like enabling binding on Spring app `@EnableBinding`,`ContextRefreshedEvent` starts getting fired multiple times.

For example,

```
public interface MessageBinding {
    @Input("test")
    KStream<Long, String> messagesIn();
}

@EnableBinding(MessageBinding.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class ComponentX {

        @Autowired
        ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @EventListener
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Fired event");
        }
    }
```

If you remove `@EnableBinding` annotation, `ContextRefreshedEvent` will only be fired once.

If you add it, the event will be fired 5 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to check for your specific ApplicationContext like this:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    if (event.getApplicationContext().equals(this.applicationContext)) {
        System.out.println("Fired only once!");
    }
}
```